# Difference in DELETE performance between physical (snapshot based) and logical (basebackup) clones

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We have a relatively large PostgreSQL database (500G - 1TB) and want to perform a big migration task.
The migration consists in a bunch of ALTER, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT.

We have performed this migration on logical (via base backup) clone of the production database for quite some time by using wal-e base backups and the whole process took ~24hrs.

We then did the same using a physical copy of the volume to be as live-like as possible and - surprise! - it took 50hrs. Not a one-off and can be repeated.

It feels like there's something 'physical' that's not then logically replicated.

In particular we have noticed that some (2M statements) DELETE statements that take ~300-500ms each on a logical clone, take ~1s on a physical clone.

What could explain this behaviour and what do you think we can do to prevent it?

Comment: Do you have FK to the table you're deleting data from ?

Comment: No FKs, but many references - all them with no action specified as delete rule

Comment: I'd try to disable all triggers on the table before deleting rows from physical replica and check if it makes any difference (surely assuming you have another copy to restore data in case something goes wrong) . You can do it by either `alter table disable trigger all` or `set session_replication_role='replica'` . Another thing to compare is a number of dead tuples in logical replica and physical copy, and do vacuum if need .

Comment: Why do you think triggers/FKs/indexes may have an impact on the physical replica but not the logical one?

Comment: Triggers are surely disabled during logical replication on subscriber node. I'm not sure what happened when you run dml against the logical replica - if triggers are still disabled , it explains better performance .

Comment: Ha! Sorry, wrong terminology there... - what I meant by logical replica I meant a DB that's been restored from a base backup VS a volume snapshot.